# Clear canvas button

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to create a button to clear a canvas, but with no success.

My codes for this

JS

```
function clearcanvas1(){
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
var w = canvas.width; canvas.width = 1; canvas.width = w; 
}
```

HTML

```
<button onmouseover="clearcanvas1()">clear</button>
```

I have tried other options such as

```
canvas.width = canvas.width;
```

and

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
```

At the moment I have substituted the clear button for a location.reload function, but it upsets a secondary canvas on the same page which I want to operate independently.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be getting the `canvas` element within your function (or indeed its context)...

```
function clearcanvas1()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Obviously, you'll need to update `document.getElementById()` to represent the correct ID for your markup, or you can use `document.getElementsByTagName()`.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly.
I had no idea you'd have to work the context in like that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

on the button call the below function

```
function clearall()
{
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas+id");
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
```

hope this will help you. Be aware this function will clear everything in the canvas.